# Create a .csv content mapping ahead of content export

Tags: csv, export, umbraco, export-to-csv, craftcms

I'm facing a little challenge with one of my client and I was hoping someone would have suggestions.

I have a client using an Umbraco 4 CMS environment and they are keen to move their production environment to Craft CMS. They have asked if there was any possibility to generate a .csv file mapping all content currently on their site, for Craft CMS to read/fetch content, thus avoiding them to manually copy/paste all their pages.

I've had a look at the Umbraco community pages and couldn't find anything around this format.

Thanks a million for your replies!

Comment: You couldn’t use csv format for this anyway.  There is likely to be html in any export and that just would not play well with csv.

Comment: The output format doesn't really matter I understand, as long as it allows Craft CMS to map content and import it back we'd be all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many plugins available, but unfortunately, the compatibility list hasn't been updated, so it may be a trial and error process.

I've tested the following on an Umbraco 4 solution, and was created for Umbraco 6.

This should work and meets your needs, with a bit of flexibility - https://our.umbraco.com/packages/website-utilities/eyecatch-csv-export/

EDIT: However, alteration may be required if it needs to be read by Craft